# Modificar ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid

Teniendo el siguiente componente:

http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/editable

¿Alguien me puede decir como poner un componente que no sea un input, por ejemplo un checkbox, dentro de la fila?

Viendo el código del enlace anterior he intentado hacer esto:

```
const check = <input type="checkbox"/>;

let _rows = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        _rows.push({
            id: i,
            task: "Task" + i,
            complete: Math.min(100, Math.round(Math.random() * 110)),
            priority: ['Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low'][Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)],
            issueType: ['Bug', 'Improvement', 'Epic', 'Story'][Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)],
            startDate: randomDate(new Date(2015, 3, 1), new Date()),
            completeDate: randomDate(new Date(), new Date(2016, 0, 1)),
            mycolumn: {check}
    });
}
```

Pero no funciona.

Alguna ayuda, por favor.
Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

[Aquí sale un ejemplo](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/cell-selection-events) donde usan un checkbox a través de `enableRowSelect` para procesar las columnas seleccionadas. Algo como:

```
onRowSelect: function(rows) {
  this.setState({selectedRows: rows});
}
//...


<ReactDataGrid enableRowSelect={true} onRowSelect={this.onRowSelect} />
```

Si necesitas algo más personalizado, otra opción es que uses [uno de los editores integrados](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/documentation.html#/componentsDocs) en el ui de la librería, donde efectivamente hay un `CheckboxEditor`. [Aquí sale un ejemplo](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/built-in-editors)  de como usar un editor integrado, no necesariamente `CheckboxEditor`, pero te puedes hacer una idea viendo como usan `AutoComplete` o `DropDownEditor`.

Comment: Si lo había visto antes, pero esos componentes estan dentro de ReactDataGridPlugins, ¿verdad? Esta librería me da error al hacer su importación a mi fichero para usar los componentes. De ahí que no lo use.

Comment: @XXx pero entonces tu problema es que no te funciona ReactDataGridPlugins, no lo que pusiste en la pregunta. Deberías agregar eso a tu pregunta, a menos que quieras crear [tu propio editor personalizado](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/src/addons/editors/CheckboxEditor.js), pero insisto, estás abordando tu problema desde el ángulo equivocado.